# Calling Tooling API via ApexClass

Tags: apex, tooling-api

I'm trying to figure out how to call Tooling API in the APEX class and get the data, 
Here is what I have done:

In Remote Site URL provide your salesforce instance.

Getting the following error:

> USER_DEBUG [77]|DEBUG|response
>
> ## Bad Message 400
>
> ```
> reason:
> Unknown Version
> ```

```
static String restGet(String endPoint, String method, String sid) {
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest hr = new HttpRequest();
    hr.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + sid);
    hr.setTimeout(60000);
    hr.setEndpoint(endPoint);
    hr.setMethod(method);
    HttpResponse r = h.send(hr);
    return r.getBody();
}

String baseURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();

String body = restGet( baseURL +
'/services/data/v47.0/tooling/query?'+
'q=SELECT Id, MasterLabel, Metadata FROM Flow WHERE MasterLabel = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(\'TEST FLOW\', \'UTF-8\') AND Status = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(\'Active\', \'UTF-8\') ORDER BY versionnumber',
'GET', UserInfo.getSessionId() );

System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ v: ' + body );
String metadata = body.substringBetween('"Metadata":{"', '}}]}');
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ v: ' + metadata );
```

Answer (score 6):

You are sending the literal string `EncodingUtil.urlEncode()` instead of calling the method to build a string. You want:

```
String body = restGet( baseURL +
'/services/data/v47.0/tooling/query?'+
'q=SELECT Id, MasterLabel, Metadata FROM Flow WHERE MasterLabel = ' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode('TEST FLOW', 'UTF-8') + ' AND Status = ' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode('Active', 'UTF-8') + ' ORDER BY versionnumber',
'GET', UserInfo.getSessionId() );
```